# a better way to check if a checkbox is defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

currently i am using

```
var email, fax, sms = false;  
    if($('#uemail:checked').val() != undefined)  
        email = true;  
    if($('#ufax:checked').val() != undefined)  
        fax = true;  
    if($('#usms:checked').val() != undefined)  
        sms = true;
```

but its such a long way to write it.

is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($('#uemail').is(':checked'))
    email = true;
```

Or even shorter:

```
email = $('#uemail').is(':checked');
```

You're passing the `:checked` selector into jQuery's `.is()` method which returns a boolean value;

- http://api.jquery.com/is/

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/), like this:

```
var email = $('#uemail:checked').length,
      fax = $('#ufax:checked').length,
      sms = $('#usms:checked').length;
```

[`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) is the length of the array of matched elements...if it's not checked, it's `0`.  And since `.length == 0` serves for `.length == false` in JavaScript you can do the short version above.  If you *need* a true/false, then just do `.length != 0` instead :)

Or, another alternative that produces booleans, just use the DOM [`.checked` property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp):

```
var email = $('#uemail')[0].checked,
      fax = $('#ufax')[0].checked,
      sms = $('#usms')[0].checked;
```

Or, no jQuery at all just use [`getElementById()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp):

```
var email = document.getElementById('uemail').checked,
      fax = document.getElementById('ufax').checked,
      sms = document.getElementById('usms').checked;
```

Comment: Was about to respond to your original comment. :o) Agreed with `[0].checked`, and was about to say that if you're going to shed jQuery, might as well go all the way. Good to see you included it in your answer. :o)

Comment: @patrick - Sorry about that, converted it here...comments don't offer enough formatting sometimes, if only we were allowed new-lines...though I do see how that would get abused quickly.

Comment: Nick - Not a problem. It was a good idea that belongs here. :o)

Comment: Either of the last two methods is the way to go in my book.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative may be to use an associative array and then loop through the keys. It would certainly be more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

```
// Initialise all the checkbox values as unknown
var items = {
  "email" : none,
  "fax"   : none,
  "sms"   : none
};

// Loop through each checkbox index
for (var index in items) {

   // Get the id of the checkbox
   var id = '#u' + index;

   // Find out if the checkbox is checked
   items[index] = $(id).is(':checked');
}
```